# Changing colnames by lookup

Tags: r, list, lookup, substitution

I have a data frame where the upper left looks like this:

```
             Row.names Chrom Position GT_1 GT_10 GT_100 GT_101 GT_103
1  SST4.03CH00_1006820     0  1006820 <NA>  TTTA   TTAA   TTTT   TTTT
2  SST4.03CH00_1006822     0  1006822 <NA>  CCCC   <NA>   CCCC   CCCC
3  SST4.03CH00_1006850     0  1006850 GGGA  GGGG   GGGG   <NA>   GGGG
4  SST4.03CH00_1117001     0  1117001 GGAA  GGGA   AAAA   GGGG   GGGA
5 SST4.03CH00_11378893     0 11378893 CCCC  <NA>   CCCA   CCCC   <NA>
```

I need to change the column headers starting with 'GT_' with an alternative name according to this list:

```
GT_1  Anna
GT_10 Beatrix
GT_100 Silvia
GT_101 Samoa
GT_103 Samurai
```

Now, I have managed to do this by transposing and merging and transposing back. However, it seems like a rather clumsy way to do this. I would appreciate a more elegant/safe solution to this recurrent task of mine.

Comment: Is your `list` a `data.frame` or a real `list`?  Try with `match` `df2[,2][match(names(df1), df2[,1])`

Comment: Sorry for being not exact. The 'list' would be a data frame.

Comment: Okay, you were a bit slow to respond.

Answer (score 1):

use the following concept to rename your columns:

```
df <- data.frame (a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10), d = rnorm(10))


old <- c('a','b','c')
new <- c('z','x', 'y')
rename <- na.omit(match(names(df),old))
names(df)[rename] <- new[rename]
```

Comment: I assume that in this case the length of the old and new vectors have to be equal?

Comment: yes exactly like your rename list (`old` and `new` can be replaced with the corresponding dataframe data. (`renamedf[,1]` and `renamedf[,2]`)